# MariaDB / MySQL - generate a stored column based on values in previous rows

Tags: mysql

For long and boring reasons† I need to add a generated column (**running_total**) to a very simple database with one table (**solar_generation**) which sums up a column (**amount**) in the current row, when inserted, and the previous 19 rows. So 20 rows in total.

```
ALTER TABLE solar_generation ADD running_total INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (select sum(amount) from solar_generation order by solar_generation.id asc limit 20) STORED;
```

It's not liking it, though - it tells me I cannot use a **select** in the generation statement. So...any bright ideas how I can do it, please?

† I'm trying to get a solar generation monitor on my Home Assistant dashboard, but doesn't like the complicated select query I'm giving it, and just wants to pull one column out of one row. So I figure adding a generated column would keep it happy. At the cost of my sanity, it would appear.

Comment: You might consider using a view defined with a window function.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that you cannot perform a calculation as generated column that needs data from other rows or other tables. Generated columns can only perform deterministic calculation within the current row.

You need to create a view if you would like to include this calculated column in your database structure.

Restrictions on generated columns are documented in the [mysql manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html):

> Literals, deterministic built-in functions, and operators are
> permitted. A function is deterministic if, given the same data in
> tables, multiple invocations produce the same result, independently of
> the connected user. Examples of functions that are nondeterministic
> and fail this definition: CONNECTION_ID(), CURRENT_USER(), NOW().
>
> Stored functions and loadable functions are not permitted.
>
> Stored procedure and function parameters are not permitted.
>
> Variables (system variables, user-defined variables, and stored
> program local variables) are not permitted.
>
> Subqueries are not permitted.
>
> A generated column definition can refer to other generated columns,
> but only those occurring earlier in the table definition. A generated
> column definition can refer to any base (nongenerated) column in the
> table whether its definition occurs earlier or later.
>
> The AUTO_INCREMENT attribute cannot be used in a generated column
> definition.
>
> An AUTO_INCREMENT column cannot be used as a base column in a
> generated column definition.
>
> If expression evaluation causes truncation or provides incorrect input
> to a function, the CREATE TABLE statement terminates with an error and
> the DDL operation is rejected.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that with generated column as described by Shadow.

Calculating columns during insert is seldom the best solution (use a view/a stored procedure instead), but if you really want to do that, you can use a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_solar_generation
BEFORE INSERT
ON solar_generation
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE v_sum INT;
  
  SELECT SUM(amount) INTO v_sum
  FROM solar_generation 
  ORDER BY solar_generation.id desc 
  LIMIT 19;
  
  SET new.running_total = ifnull(v_sum,0) + new.amount;
END
```